# How can i simulate PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST error in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

how can i simulate the "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST" error in mysql for node.js?

If i get the error, my application crashes, and i dont know how to reproduce this error.

thank you.

Comment: Don't know anything about `node.js` but isn't this error happens when the connection to the DB is lost? In that case, in order to reproduce it you need to stop the mysql service. But I'm really not sure because I'm not a node.js developer

Comment: Please post results of SELECT @@version;  and  SELECT @@log_warnings;  so we know what version and warning level you are using.  Also your code that CONNECTs to mysql through the end of the request handling.

Answer (score 0):

it really sounds like your application is crashing because is not handling the error. You may want to check in the files where you initialize the MySQL connection if that's the case.

As for the error, the "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST" is just a Generic Error Object. If you want to throw it inside your application (not actually stopping MySQL from working):

```
const err = new Error('Connection lost: The server closed the connection.');
err.fatal = true;
err.code = 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST';
throw err;
```

Put that in the line of code where you want to throw the error.

If you want to emulate that MySql is throwing this error, one (unrecommended way) is to hack into the lib. The `Connections` object has access to the `Protocol` object, which has a hidden method `_delegateError` that's the one fired when there's a protocol error. Source: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/Protocol.js

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution for connection protocol lost. This solution solved me

Here the data base connection

`const mysql = require('mysql');`

`const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'******',
    database:'db_name'
});`
`connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) console.log(error);
     else console.log('SQL Database Connected!');
});`

`module.exports = connection;`
`

just run the node server using pm2
Ex. pm2 start app.js
[install the npm pm2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)